# How to user convert files to Linux format in bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have many `*.c` and `*.h` files in a directory. I want to convert all these files to `Linux` compatible format. I've attempted following script and it runs but nothing get converted.

And I also need to check if everything get converted successfully. Therefore I filter and compare its output to the original file in the directory.

How could I fix it?

```
#!/bin/bash

function  converting_files() {

   cd "/path/to/dir" &&  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 | dos2unix

}

function success_of_converting_files() {

 FILES=colsim_xfig/xfig.3.2.5c/*
 #There are 250 files in the dir and not all but most of them are .c and .h
 for i in {000..249} ; do                 
   for f in "$Files" ; do 
   #I think *.txt line ending is fine as we only want to compare
     dos2unix < myfile{i}.txt | cmp -s - myfile{i}.txt
   done 
   done        
}

function main() {

   converting_files
   success_of_converting           
}
```

I basically need to convert all files to `LF` line endings.
p.S: Total number of files in the directory is 249. The number of files in the directory is not fixed so, it would be better if I could have an arbitrary number of arguments instead of just 249.

Comment: What do you mean by Linux compatible format? Isn't `c` an extension for C source code and `h` for header files? Their content should be human readable I guess.

Comment: @Kulfy: CRLF line endings to LF line endings

Comment: Do you really need a script when you can do this using sed?

Comment: @Kulfy: Unfortunately yes, above two functions are just 2 functions of much larger script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the command

```
cd "/path/to/dir" &&  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 | dos2unix
```

you are piping a null-separated list of filenames to `xargs`, but not supplying a command to run on them. In this case, `xargs` defaults to executing `/bin/echo` on them: in other words, it just outputs a space-separated list of filenames on standard output, which you then pipe to `dos2unix`. The result is that instead of converting the *files* to Unix format, you just convert the list of *filenames*.

Presumably what you intended was

```
cd "/path/to/dir" &&  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

However you could achieve the same more compactly using the `find` command's `-exec` or `-execdir` e.g.

```
find "/path/to/dir/" -type f -execdir dos2unix {} +
```

or (to restrict to `.c` and `.h` files)

```
find "/path/to/dir/" -type f -name '*.[ch]' -execdir dos2unix {} +
```

Comment: Restricting to .c and .h files seems like a very good idea -- I'm not sure what `dos2unix` would do to a compiled binary.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it seems to be smart enough not to try (`dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x02 found at line 1` `dos2unix: Skipping binary file a.out`)